# Getting Combined Total Number Of MySQL Cells With Same Value:

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a forums project and the struggle I am faced with is gathering the total amount of MySQL cells with the same value. The point of this is to get the total number of replies in a specific topic in the forums.

In my specific circumstance, I have a table called **post** . In **post** , there is a cell called **post_topic** , which is the same value as **topic_id** from my table, **topic** (this is to attach replies directly to the topic). The values in **post_topic** range from 1 (being the first topic), 2 (being the second topic), etc.

What I am trying to do is get the total amount of replies (post_topic) that have the same value, for example if in **post_topic** there were 40 cells with the value "7", how can I get MySQL to only cherry pick those 40 cells out of the hundreds of others and echo it through PHP?

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
$sql = "SELECT
               post_topic,
               topic_id
             FROM
               post,
               topic";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

echo '<button>' *** need the value to go here! *** '</button>;
```

I'm self taught, so if you write it in code I will be able to understand it, the problem is I just haven't figured out how to do it myself yet. I'm not great with terms and whatnot and that's probably why I couldn't find my answer on Google, so sorry if this is a frequent repeater. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: stop using mysql_* and read up on the WHERE clause.

Comment: I understand the WHERE clause: Ex, "SELECT post_topic FROM post WHERE post_topic = '7'"; I'm trying to get the total count of cells with that value.  I don't understand how to do the specific part I am trying to do.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You possibly need to read up on mysql aggregate functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to find number of posts

```
select count(post_topic) from post group by post_topic
```

you can also check for specific post by adding `having` clause.

```
select count(post_topic) from post group by post_topic having post_topic = 7
```

I hope it helps.